# Loop through each collection in a database -- mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to apply a query ofor every collection in a database in mongodb. The database have 140 collections, the query is this:

```
import pymongo
client=pymongo.MongoClient("localhost",27017)
db=client.EcoEmp_db

pipeline=[db.D12.aggregate([
{"$unwind":"$_id"},
{"$addFields":{
"bibliographic.link":"$link",
"bibliographic.keywords":"$keywords",
"bibliographic.abstract":"$abstract",
"bibliographic.author":"$author"
}},
{
"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$bibliographic"}
},
{"$out": "D12_p"}
])]
```

I run this pipeline from `pymoongo` and works correctly. To iterate for every collection I do this:

```
import pymongo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = connection['EcoEmp_db']
    collection = db.collection_names(include_system_collections=False)
    for collect in collection:
        db.db[collect].aggregate([
        {"$unwind":"$_id"},
        {"$addFields":{
        "bibliographic.link":"$link",
        "bibliographic.keywords":"$keywords",
        "bibliographic.abstract":"$abstract",
        "bibliographic.author":"$author"
        }},
        {
        "$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$bibliographic"}
        },
        {"$out": collect+"_p"}
        ])
```

But I get anything, it seem that dont works, any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the result in dictionary format, where *your_db_name* is your database name:

```
collections = your_db_name.collection_names()
for col in collections:
    col_x = your_db_name[col].find()
    for item in col_x:
        print(item)
```